# GWT. Vertical scrollbar in DataGrid doesn't appear

Tags: gwt, datagrid, scrollbar

I added DataGrid into my project. But I can see only 3 records in it. And I can't scroll DataGrid to see all other records. There isn't scrollbar in DataGrid. I placed Datagrid into the ResizeLayoutPanel.  ResizeLayoutPanel is in DockLayoutPanel. DockLayoutPanel is in RootLayoutPanel.

```
DataGrid<Log> myDataGrid = new DataGrid<Log>();
myDataGrid.setWidth("100%");
myDataGrid.setAutoHeaderRefreshDisabled(true);

ResizeLayoutPanel lp = new ResizeLayoutPanel();     
lp.add(myDataGrid);
lp.setWidth("100%");    
lp.setHeight("100%");

DockLayoutPanel p = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
p.addNorth(someLabel, 2);
p.addSouth(lp, 10);     
p.add(someTabPanel);

RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();     
rp.add(p);
```

Please, help.

Comment: I've found my mistake. I set myDataGrid.setPageSize(3), so I saw only 3 rows without vertical scrollbar. Thanks everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Assign height to datagrid like

```
myDataGrid.setHeight(((Window.getClientHeight()*50)/100)+"px");
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the size of your `DataGrid`.

```
myDataGrid.setPixelSize( width, height );
myDataGrid.setTableWidth( width, Unit.PX );
myDataGrid.setMinimumTableWidth( 800, Unit.PX );
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help too. Changing width parameters makes horizontal scrollbar available, but changing height parameter hasn't any effects. Vertical scrollbar doesn't appear. `myDataGrid.setPixelSize( 1000, 100);
myDataGrid.setTableWidth( 1000, Unit.PX );
myDataGrid.setMinimumTableWidth( 1000, Unit.PX );`

Comment: hmm..try to add your `DataGrid` widget on a `HorizontalPanel` and set the pixel size for the panel. `panel.setPixelSize(1000, 100)` or add that lp (ResizeLayoutPanel) on the center of the dockPanel and see if it takes effect.

Comment: Thank you @rui for your reply. I've tried both choices. But none worked for me. I didn't see any changes on the screen.

Comment: Maybe problem is in the panels structure. Could you give me working structure with DataGrid as an example?